# How to get the JSON array for data from reddit?

Tags: android, arrays, reddit, json

I'm having difficulty rapping my head around the concept of JSON arrays and how exactly to target a specific array from a JSON response.

So, my goal is to get from http://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/.json the "URL" key value from the "data" objects which are held in the "children" array, but I'm not sure how to get through the multiple levels and store it in something.

If I had to take a guess I would save the query's array and then I would simply say queryArray.children[1][1].URL to get the first URL of the first data array.

Any examples of using reddit in particular would be amazing! I'm really confused with the structure of the JSON response that reddit.com has.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSONObject and JSONArray to parse the result

```
String jsonString = "{...}"; //reddit json answer to the request
JSONObject redditjson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray children = (JSONArray)redditjson .get("children");
JSONObject data = (JSONObject)children.get(0);
String url = data.getString("url");
```

Don't forget to use it inside a try/catch block